# Mockito: how to use when(instance.meth).thenAnswer without mock

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have try following code:

```
package ro.ex;

/**
 * Created by roroco on 11/11/14.
 */

import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


public class ExTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {
    class C {
        public String m() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void testM() throws Exception {
        when(new C().m()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                return (String) args[0];
            }
        });

    }
}
```

i hope i can change a real instance meth not a mock, but above code raise:

```
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

**my question is:** how to fix it.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you want a real instance to behave like it's not a real instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a sample code you created to ask a question here but in real, `C` should be the class under test (not a class within your test).

```
Class MyClassToTest {

public String m() {...}

}
```

Now in your test, mock class C. `@Mock C c` and followed by `when(c.m()).thenAnswer....`. in the test method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would need that, but you can use `spy`:

```
public void testM() throws Exception {
    C c = Mockito.spy(new C());

    // actual method
    c.m();

    // stubbed method
    when(c.m()).thenAnswer(...);
}
```

Alternatively, you can `mock` the object, and call `thenCallRealMethod()` when needed.